# How to import songs from Music Library with all id3 tags

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using `MPMediaPickerController` to fetch/import songs from Music Library, which works fine. However it doesn't give complete info of the song like Album Art, Artist Info, Album Info etc. Can anyone please help on how to import song with complete info. Below is my code. `self.fullPath` is an `NSString` containing the path to `Document Directory`.

```
typedef enum {
kEDSupportedMediaTypeAAC = 'aac',
kEDSupportedMediaTypeMP3 = '.mp3',
kEDSupportedMediaTypeWAV = '.wav',
kEDSupportedMediaTypeAIFF = 'aiff'
} EDSupportedMediaType;

-(void)importIPodMusic {
MPMediaPickerController *mediaPicker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeMusic];  

mediaPicker.delegate = self;
mediaPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = YES; // this is the default
mediaPicker.prompt = NSLocalizedString(@"Choose your song:", nil);
mediaPicker.navigationController.toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

[self presentViewController:mediaPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

```
-(void)mediaPicker:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection {
[mediaPicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

[self importSongsForArray:mediaItemCollection.items];
```

}

```
-(void)importSongsForArray: (NSArray*)array {   
@autoreleasepool {
    float progress = 0.0f;
    float index = 0.0f;

    for (MPMediaItem *item in array) {
        NSURL *url = [item valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
        NSString *title = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
        AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];
        AVAssetReader *reader = [[AVAssetReader alloc] initWithAsset:asset error:nil];
        NSMutableArray *myOutputs =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSString *fileURL = @"";

        for(AVAssetTrack *track in [asset tracks])
        {
            NSMutableDictionary* audioReadSettings = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            [audioReadSettings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM]
                                 forKey:AVFormatIDKey];

            AVAssetReaderTrackOutput *output=[AVAssetReaderTrackOutput assetReaderTrackOutputWithTrack:track outputSettings:nil];
            [myOutputs addObject:output];
            [reader addOutput:output];

            NSArray *formats = track.formatDescriptions;
            for (int i=0; i<[formats count]; i++) {
                CMFormatDescriptionRef format = (__bridge CMFormatDescriptionRef)[formats objectAtIndex:i];

                // Check the format types
                FourCharCode mediaSubType = CMFormatDescriptionGetMediaSubType(format);
                CMMediaType mediaType = CMFormatDescriptionGetMediaType(format);

                NSLog(@"mediaType: %u, mediaSubType: %u", (unsigned int)mediaType, (unsigned int)mediaSubType);

                if (mediaSubType == kEDSupportedMediaTypeMP3) {
                    fileURL = [self.fullPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp3", title]];
                    break;
                }                    
            }
        }
        [reader startReading];
        NSFileHandle *fileHandle ;
        NSFileManager *fm=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
        if(![fm fileExistsAtPath:fileURL])
        {
            NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] init];
            [fm createFileAtPath:fileURL contents:data attributes:nil];
        }else{
            NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] init];
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fileURL];
            [fm removeItemAtURL:url error:nil];
            [fm createFileAtPath:fileURL contents:data attributes:nil];

        }
        fileHandle=[NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:fileURL];
        [fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];

        AVAssetReaderOutput *output=[myOutputs objectAtIndex:0];
        int totalBuff=0;
        int test = 1;
        while(test == 1)
        {
            CMSampleBufferRef ref=[output copyNextSampleBuffer];

            if(ref==NULL)
                test = 0;

            if(ref==NULL)
                break;
            //copy data to file
            //read next one
            AudioBufferList audioBufferList;
            NSMutableData *data;
            CMBlockBufferRef blockBuffer;
            CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer(ref, NULL, &audioBufferList, sizeof(audioBufferList), NULL, NULL, 0, &blockBuffer);

            for( int y=0; y<audioBufferList.mNumberBuffers; y++ )
            {
                AudioBuffer audioBuffer = audioBufferList.mBuffers[y];
                void *frame = audioBuffer.mData;

                data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithBytes:frame length:audioBuffer.mDataByteSize];
            }
            totalBuff++;
            NSLog(@"\n%d\n",totalBuff);

            //            int time = [self.mediaPlayer durationOfCurrentItem];

            //            if (totalBuff * 2 <= time + 1)
            [fileHandle writeData:data];

        }
        [fileHandle closeFile];

        progress = ++index/[array count];
        NSLog(@"\n%lf\n",progress);
    }
}

[self reloadData];
```

}